# Can't use Python dataclass with PyQt5 widget

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-dataclasses

I've got a class that stores some Qt controls, so:

```
class Controls:
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = QLabel()
```

Then I can do:

```
x = Controls()
x.label.setText("Hello")
```

This works. The class actually has dozens of controls, not just the one I've used for illustration, so I wanted to use the more succinct dataclass notation:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, init=False)
class Controls:
    label: QLabel
```

but having done this, I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'Controls' object has no attribute 'label'

I've tried initialising the field (`= QLabel()`), I've also tried using `field` with `default` or `default_factory`, with no joy.

I wondered if anyone knew what the problem was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to let the constructor be implemented(remove `init=False`):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Controls:
    label: QLabel = field(default_factory=QLabel)
```